# The "L" of \ln in mathsf

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I have redefined `\ln` with a sans-serif font but I am afraid that students misread "ln" as "In".

Do you know if there is another sans-serif font that I could use (maybe only for the "L" of "ln")? I'm satisfied with all the other letters.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\ln\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\ln}{\mathsf{ln}}

\begin{document}
$\ln(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want redefine \ln? It is very nice in Compute Modern. Often it is written like as \log also if the base is neperian.

Comment: You can have a look at https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html and pick a font with a curved `l`. But do you really believe the risk of confusion is real?

Comment: @Colas Can you add some background information why you are using sans serif font for for ln? Maybe this would inspire some alternative approaches to the problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have decided to write all the classical objects (sin, cos, exp, ln, etc.) with a sans serif font.

Comment: @campa Do know how can I use only the letter "l" from one of these fonts? For example, from `Atkinson Hyperlegible` (https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/atkinsonhyperlegible/)

Comment: @Colas Wouldn't it be easier to change the operator font instead of redefining all the macros like `\ln`?

Comment: Maybe but redefining all the macros like `\ln` doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 3):

As samcarter suggests in [her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707099/the-l-of-ln-in-mathsf#comment1758002_707099) using a different font altogether for operators is easier. I'd say that a properly scaled cantarell might do the trick. The code comes from an answer (likely by egreg `:-)`) which I can't find right now...

The result is IMO horrible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cantarell@scale}{.9467}
\DeclareSymbolFont{sansops}{OT1}{cantarell-LF}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{sansops}{bold}{OT1}{cantarell-LF}{b}{n}
\renewcommand*{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symsansops}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textsf{ln}$\ln$
\textsf{sin}$\sin$
\textsf{exp}$\exp$
$\ln(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much better than Frankensteining together characters from different fonts!